# Crop image in card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

I've built this horizontal card with an image on the left, and I've specified a min height for the card which is important.

Currently the image fits in the card using width: 100% and height: 100%, but i want it to use the full height of the parent and then crop the width of it.

I am using Bootstrap 4

HTML

```
<div class="card mb-3 rounded shadow">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="{{ course.media[0].fileName }}" class="card-image" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card-body">
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">{{ course.courseNumber }}</span>
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ course.name }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ course.description }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
$nav-red: #e51400;

.card {
    max-width: 540px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.card-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.card-body span{
    background-color: $nav-red !important;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not sure about your goal, I think that css "object-fit" property is what are you looking for. I have forked simple project that based on your provided HTML and CSS + Angular: https://angular-bootstrap-4-sandbox-mc8neu.stackblitz.io

Main important difference is that I've added "min-height" to a .card > .row element, to fix fitting problem.

Final code looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="card mb-3 rounded shadow">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="{{ course.media[0].fileName }}" class="card-image img-fluid img-cover" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card-body">
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">{{ course.courseNumber }}</span>
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ course.name }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ course.description }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.card {
    max-width: 540px;
    > .row {
        min-height: 200px;
    }
}

.card-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.card-body span{
    background-color: #e51400 !important;
    float: right;
}

.img-cover {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```